# ScheduledExecutorService. how to run two tasks after some timeinterval in 2 seperate services

Tags: java, android, wcf, scheduledexecutorservice

I am trying to implement continuously running background tasks for my app.
For that i used `ScheduledExecutorService` class.
I have 2 services `Service A` and `Service B` both have a task that runs all the time after some time interval. For that i used this following in `Service A` and `Service B`

This is the code which is common in both service classes.

```
Runnable postNotificationRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            // statements here}
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(postNotificationRunnable, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Now the problem is when i run app both services starts but only only scheduledExecutorService of `Service A` runs other one doesn't run. what i am doing wrong? 
P.S i am using ScheduledExecutorService for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The `ScheduledExecutorService` will wait for your tasks to finish, iff one takes longer than the *rate* you specify (in your case 1000 seconds). Have a look at the respective [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

> [...] If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

Since your services seem to behave like daemons (and therefore keep running until the application is shut down), you could do it like this:

```java
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        pool.execute(postNotificationRunnable);
    }
}, 0L, 1000L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Simply delegate the actual execution of your services to a separate `pool` that doesn't affect the `scheduler`.

Comment: When the scheduler repeats, how to know from which pool is being repeated? If he has two schedulers running, how to know after 1000L (your set repeated time) which service is repeated?